# Django - Save forms in the same data table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I'm having problem in saving selected choices in the same row of data table for each participant).

I have 2 forms. The first form is for some data and a multiple-choice question. The second form is another multiple-choice question. It also means I have 2 pages, after submit answers for page 1, it will redirect to page 2 for question 2.

When I try to be a participant and choose answers, the selected choices are saved in different data table. Pictures and code are displayed below.

[image]

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Survey

class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    BAT='Batman'
    SUPER='Superman'
    IRON='Ironman'
    WHATMOVIE1 = [
    (BAT, 'Batman'),
    (SUPER, 'Superman'),
    (IRON, 'Ironman'),
    ]
    movie_1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WHATMOVIE1, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = ["location", "age", 
        "marital_status", "education", 'movie_1']

class SurForm(forms.ModelForm):
    APP='Apple'
    BAN='Banana'
    LEM='Lemon'
    WHATMOVIE2 = [
    (APP, 'Apple'),
    (BAN, 'Banana'),
    (LEM, 'Lemon'),
    ]
    movie_2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WHATMOVIE2, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = [ 'movie_2']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .forms import SurveyForm, SurForm

def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = "Questionnaire"
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nextpage'))
    else:
        form = SurveyForm()
    return render(request, "homepage.html", {"form": form})

def nextpage(request):
    title = "Next page"
    form = SurForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "nextpage.html", context)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import SurveyForm, SurForm
from .models import Survey, Sur

    class SurAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        form = SurForm

    class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ["location", "age", 
        "marital_status", "education", 
        "movie_1"]
        form = SurveyForm


    admin.site.register(Survey, SurveyAdmin)
    admin.site.register(Sur, SurAdmin)
```

What should I do to save all selected answers in the same row for each participant?

Comment: Think about using form wizards, it does exactly what u want:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: Thank you @OhadtheLad. I'm trying this (formtools in django1.8).

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different models, that is why they are getting separated. You need to create a relation between them, using a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) can solve the problem. Something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, primary_key=True)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name
```

Optionally, you can just combine the two models.

Comment: I tried this one. But I have no idea what I should put in admin.py to show them up. I can't just define list_display = ["location", "age", 
 "marital_status", "education", "movie_1", "movie_2"] as usual.

Comment: Did you try `admin.site.register(Restaurant)` in your admin.py of your app?

Comment: Yes, Just try with above admin.site.register but doesn't work. The list_display is in my admin.py

Comment: from django.contrib import admin

from .forms import SurveyForm
from .models import Survey, Movie4

class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ["location", "age", 
 "marital_status", "education", 
 "movie_1", "movie_2", "movie_3"]
 form = SurveyForm


admin.site.register(Survey, SurveyAdmin)
admin.site.register(Movie4)

Comment: I also tried to combine the two models. But the thing is, I can't display them separately. They are displayed as {{form}}. I tried to display them as {{survey.location}} or {{survey.movie_1}} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you make sure that the form is being sent to `context`?

Comment: Yes. I just added my admin.py after using OnetoOneField.